# Android Studio 3.3 RC3 Theme Editor Missing

Tags: android-studio

Since installing Android Studio 3.3RC3 from the preview site, the Theme Editor is missing. When viewing my `styles.xml` file, there is no button to open the theme editor.

Pressing SHIFT twice and searching for the Theme Editor reveals the icon, but when the pane comes up it shows a blank text editor.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119271605), the Theme Editor has been disabled.

The fact that you get something with the double-shift search option suggests that there is a bug somewhere, as if the Theme Editor is an ex-feature, it should not show up in searches either.

Comment: Man, that was a very useful tool for keeping things organized. I am very disappointed.

Comment: The issue page doesn't get into much detail about the thinking behind this decision. Why did they choose to remove it? Maybe we will never know.

Comment: I'm using 3.3.2 and it's missing here too.  It would sure be nice if they'd mention it in their docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor

Comment: Glad that they removed it. I guess they finally will be able to write good docs for theming, instead of working/maintaining a feature that aims to dumbify the user.

Comment: Explanation of the theme editor removal can be found here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120384109#comment4

Answer (score 3):

Theme Editor is still missing in 3.5 edition. The fact that it hasn't made itself back in makes me think it's been permanently cut. A real shame when there is not a good replacement. It's still possible to edit the theme directly through the styles.xml file, but you will need to look up the syntax yourself for each component.

This article does reference the name of several of the components as well as what they are in project:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2467490&seqNum=5

Answer (score 3):

Android Studio 3.4 for Mac still doesn't have Theme Editor back.
Alternative way can be like,

1. In '**values/styles.xml**', you can see soft coded theme colors.
2. It can be changed in '**values/colors.xml**'.
3. Click number thumbnail image on right side of linenumbers, then you will see color editor

[image: Click number thumbnail image on right side of linenumbers, then you will see color editor]

Answer (score 3):

According to android docs Theme Editor is no longer a part of Android Studio

[image]

Now if u want to change colors u need to go to

**res > values > colors.xml**
or
**res > values > styles.xml > ctrl + click on desirable style > colors.xml**

and click at color square to the left of te current line

Answer (score 2):

it seems theme editor is removed also for android studio 4.0
i have search with search anywhere feature and got
[image]

but you can edit appearance of your styles by clicking on the left of each items specified under res/values/styles.xml. this screen shot is for a color edition
[image]

Answer (score -8):

It shows here in Android studio 3.3.2[image]

Comment: That is not the Theme Editor. That is a list of themes to choose from for the layout editor preview.

Comment: this is a simple themes list... as i understand, the editor has been disabled/unmounted some time ago