# android studio 3.3 theme editor not showing anything

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.3

As soon as I updated android studio the theme editor isn't working at all and it also doesn't show up when I edit the apptheme-parent in styles.xml

[image]

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53891582/android-studio-3-3-rc3-theme-editor-missing