# Can't find theme editor on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.3

I've checked for this question before and I was told to check the right hand corner of my android studio or check tool.  Then go to Android but there is no "open theme editor" at the top right corner of my Android Studio and I still cannot find it in "tools>android"

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53891582/android-studio-3-3-rc3-theme-editor-missing

Answer (score 1):

you can open it using the `android studio` search everywhere feature. Press `Shift` twice and type `theme`, it will show you the theme editor in the options.

Comment: This feature has also been removed from here